# Angular 5 Application not working in Firefox v48.0.1 or < 50.0

Tags: angular, firefox, cross-browser, angular-cli, libraries

I am trying to run my Angular Application in older versions of Browsers because of project scope. Application is working fine in latest versions and in Chrome. Seems like issue is with IE10 and Mozilla Firefox ( Firefox version < 50 ). I am running my app currently with 48.0.1 and I am getting simple one liner issue in Console that reads.

**TypeError: this is undefined** That's it.

I tried to google and found one similar git hub problem.

This is the closes solution I found.
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9340

I tried to follow steps where issue was related to uglifyjs-webpack-plugin and move it to previous version 1.1.5. I tried that also with these commands.

```
npm i uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@1.1.5 --save-exact
rm -rf package-lock.json node_modules
npm install
```

Now issue is I can still see some other versions 1.2.5 and 0.4.6 in my package-lock.json file. I manually deleted that but still no solution.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.1.5",
}
```

**package-lock.json**

```
"@angular/cli": {

    "dependencies": {

        "requires": {
            ...
            "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.2.5",
        }
        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": {
          "version": "1.2.5",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/-/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-1.2.5.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-hIQJ1yxAPhEA2yW/i7Fr+SXZVMp+VEI3d42RTHBgQd2yhp/1UdBcR3QEWPV5ahBxlqQDMEMTuTEvDHSFINfwSw==",
          "dev": true,
          "requires": {
            "cacache": "10.0.4",
            "find-cache-dir": "1.0.0",
            "schema-utils": "0.4.5",
            "serialize-javascript": "1.5.0",
            "source-map": "0.6.1",
            "uglify-es": "3.3.9",
            "webpack-sources": "1.1.0",
            "worker-farm": "1.6.0"
          },
          "dependencies": {
            "source-map": {
              "version": "0.6.1",
              "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map/-/source-map-0.6.1.tgz",
              "integrity": "sha512-UjgapumWlbMhkBgzT7Ykc5YXUT46F0iKu8SGXq0bcwP5dz/h0Plj6enJqjz1Zbq2l5WaqYnrVbwWOWMyF3F47g==",
              "dev": true
            }
          }
        }

        ....

        "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": {
          "version": "1.1.5",
          "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/-/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-1.1.5.tgz",
          "integrity": "sha512-YBGc9G7dv12Vjx8vUQs54DZgAXVf04LlG6dNNiEbTZjL3PbUqiY4uPB9Kv+fUJaqRskEGva/lS7sh08yJr7jnA==",
          "requires": {
            "cacache": "10.0.4",
            "find-cache-dir": "1.0.0",
            "schema-utils": "0.3.0",
            "serialize-javascript": "1.5.0",
            "source-map": "0.6.1",
            "uglify-es": "3.2.2",
            "webpack-sources": "1.1.0",
            "worker-farm": "1.6.0"
          }
        },

        "webpack": {
            "requires": {
                "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "0.4.6",
            }
            "dependencies": {
                "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": {
                  "version": "0.4.6",
                  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin/-/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin-0.4.6.tgz",
                  "integrity": "sha1-uVH0q7a9YX5m9j64kUmOORdj4wk=",
                  "dev": true,
                  "requires": {
                    "source-map": "0.5.7",
                    "uglify-js": "2.8.29",
                    "webpack-sources": "1.1.0"
                  }
                },
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Any idea or help I can get. It's a critical one for project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add the polyfills as described in the docs?

Comment: Yeah all polyfill entries are by default uncommented. But other thing is I didnt find anything particular to Firefox browser. Could you help me with useful link.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: I have gone through it and all are in place properly. Mainlty browser support section. I have these lines.    /** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a  workaround available.

Just adding --aot false does the trick.

I am using command **ng serve --prod --aot=false** and it works like charm.

But is there any idea if it is safe or not? I found github discussion on the same.

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9244

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21631

Any update on this question or correct answer would be highly recommended.

Thanks,

Comment: For me, the --aot false flag was not necessary. That change would fix it, because it will require that we turn off build optimizer. If we just turn off build optimizer, and leave --aot flag on (`--build-optimizer=false`). That still works. There is a package used during build optimization that is incompatible with these versions of Firefox. The defunct package is the particular version `0.1.12` of `reflect-metadata` All this info is available in the link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/21631 posted above.